# Repositioning the required attribute on error

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

so I can't seem to figure out how to reposition the error that is thrown from the required attribute.

Example: [image: Usually the error is thrown below the text input (or any input), but I want it to be thrown to the right of the text input]

How would I go about doing that if its possible?

Comment: what framework is it? Bootstrap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly this is not possible as this is a browser feature, there are ways to change the styling using JavaScript, but not what you trying to achieve, you have to create your own validation system to be able to have full control of the validation messages styling and position, good luck